# Don't understand what is adding extra " to my key string

Tags: python, json

I am new to python and have what is probably a simple question.

I have read in JSON and now have this value in my request_body:

```json
request_body = {
  "providerName": "ProviderNameXYZ",
  "rateRequestPayments": [
    {
      "amount": 128.0,
      "creditorProfileId": "7539903942457444658",
      "debtorProfileId": "2072612712266192555",
      "paymentMethodId": "2646780961603748694016",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "userReference": "INVALID user ref automation single",
      "reconciliationId": "343546578753349"
    },
    {
      "amount": 129.0,
      "creditorProfileId": "7539903942457444658",
      "debtorProfileId": "2072612712266192555",
      "paymentMethodId": "2646780961603748694016",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "userReference": "INVALID user ref automation single",
      "reconciliationId": "343546578753340"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, I am trying to delete the key of: "amount": 128.0,:

```
del request_body["rateRequestPayments"][0]["amount"]
```

This statement works great! However, I want to parameterize it so I am not hard-coding this. So I have set elsewhere:

```
key = ["rateRequestPayments"][0]["amount"]
```

Then I try:

```
del request_body[key]
```

This fails with:  `KeyError: '["rateRequestPayments"][0]["amount"]'`

When I debug, this is the value for the key:

[image]

Why does it work hard-coded but not as a variable?  How can I make this work using the variable instead?

Comment: Please give a real [mre]. What you've shown would resolve to `key = "rateRequestPayments"["amount"]`, which is a `TypeError`.

Comment: There's a teeny tiny typo in the first line; it's currently request body where you wanted it to be request_body I assume

Comment: You can not store nested indices like this in python. You would need to store every key separately.

Comment: `del request_body[key1][key2][key3]` is the only way unfortunately. You could always wrap that in a function though.

Answer (score 1):

You cant delete the key `request_body["rateRequestPayments"][0]["amount"]` because it *doesn't* exist in `request_body`

What you can delete is

```
key = "rateRequestPayments"
index = 0
subkey = "amount"

del request_body[key][index][subkey]
```

which you could provide via a combined string that you'd need to split up, e.g.

```
combined_key = "rateRequestPayments-0-amount"
key, index, subkey = combined_key.split("-")

del request_body[key][int(index)][subkey]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead try assigning separate variables for each segment of the delete request and then using the original method to solve it:

For instance:

```
key1 = "rateRequestPayments"
key2 = 0 
key3 = "amount"

del request_body[key1][key2][key3]
```